# resuming SSH sessions

Tags: ssh, internet, session

I often end up on the interstate, using a Windows-based laptop to SSH via my cell phone connection into my Ubuntu dev machine. Between the idosyncracies of cell phone connections, plus stopping for gas etc., I get disconnected once an hour-or-so. Then I SSH back into the server. If I had vim open, I have to delete the tmp file. It's not so bad, but I would prefer to get back to what I was doing more quickly.

I vaguely remember that at some point, I SSHed into a machine and found that whatever long-running command I had been doing before I disconnected was still running.

I'm aware of tmux. I know it is a viable solution but I would prefer one that Just Works(tm).

So that's my question. Is there some way I can configure SSH to not kill my sessions if they get disconnected, so that if I reconnect I go right back to what I was doing?

Thanks

Comment: `mosh` for unstable connections. Independently, `tmux` (or `byobu`, a friendlier wrapper) as a better alternative to screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mosh - uses UDP ports to 'check and restore' the original connection.* (*analogy description, not a technologically correct description).

screen is good for opening up a new 'workspace' on your server that you can connect and disconnect to whenever you resume a session. Personally, I do terminal work between "real work" on the sly, so ssh-ing back into a session and opening screen is cumbersome, whereas Mosh will simply resume the SSH connection if the pipe is "broken" without interrupting the session.

Probably less secure at your location if you leave it open, but convenience factor for simply "getting on with it" or drifting connections means that you don't have to go through the reconnect and reattachment of screen sessions.

When in doubt, use both. :)

Comment: Disturbing to walk away from SSH, which has kept me company lo these many years. But just from the intro video, it looks like exactly what I want. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

`Screen` is a terminal multiplexer, which allows a user to access multiple separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal window or remote terminal session (such as when using SSH).

`Screen` is very useful if you're connection is not stable. For example if you want to download a file with `wget` and exit from ssh, then come back to it in an hour or so.

you can create a new 'virtual console' by simply typing `screen` in console. Then after you're disconnected from your ssh session, you can connect anytime you want, issue `screen -r` command to re-attach yourself to the virtual console

[full `screen` documentation and commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen)

Comment: Tmux is similar to Screen but has better manpage and hotkeys

Comment: I've never worked with tmux TBH

Comment: I tried to use screen and tmux. For me was manpage of tmux better.